# pandas dataframe returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading my excel sheet using pandas, iterate through line by line and do something with it. My input file has only 7 rows with some rocords in it. However when I print my dataframe, I get something like below, with additional rows with 'NaN'. And when my script iterates through index 7, it fails, with ValueError exception.

```
inputfile = r'C:\Users\users\Desktop\release\someexcel.xlsx'
dfr = pan.read_excel(inputfile, skiprows=3, sheetname=1)
print (dfr)
```

Following exception is not relevant to this question. But this was thrown, when the script try to execute the script in index 7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\PythonWorkspace\executeSQL.py", line 67, in sql_deployment
Order = int(order)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Here is my input file:

[image]

This is how the dataframe look like:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening, and how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to add `dropna(inplace=True)` method at the end?

Comment: I agree. If all your data are there, simply remove the `NaN` values.

Comment: @Jakub Thanks for your comment. Apparently, 'NaN' value cannot be checked for existence using Python equality operators. That's the reason why I was looking for guidance to see if there any Pandas operators to validate it.

Comment: Digging more in web, just found that numpy.isnan() function to check the presence of NaN. This helped me to resolve this issue.